# iPhone:Where to save the users data when icloud back up is not required

Tags: iphone, ipad, appstore-approval, data-storage

Hi i am about to submit my application to App store.I read that there are few changes in apples data storage guidelines as iCloud storage is introduced.i was saving all user's data in applications documents directory since the contents of the documents directory are automatically backed up to the iCould,if enabled,i am thinking to move them to applications Library directory.Is it approved to save contents in to library considering data storage guidelines of apple?If not where to save the data? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main options:

- Put your files in the Cache directory then they *won't* be backed up and Apple won't reject your app. However, when iOS 5 gets low on space it *may* delete all the files in there
- Put files in Documents but flag them so that they are not backed up. There's a technote ([QA1719](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342)) on how to do this. This only works in iOS 5.0.1 and later

Answer (score 0):

You can put data in Documents folder but before keep in documents folder create a folder within  Documents folder suppose namely temp. Then write the following code to not backup in iCloud.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:temp 
                          withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                           attributes:nil
                                                error:nil];
NSURL *dbURLPath = [NSURL URLWithString:temp];
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:dbURLPath];
```

Also implement the method addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL 
do not forget to include

```
#include <sys/xattr.h>

- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL {
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}
```